# SQL Query: Excluding Records by Empty Fields using Check Boxes

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I have given this one my all, and I am very sure that it is something simple that I am not seeing.

I have a MS-Access database that I am setting up for testing.  Right now, it is very simple, just 2 Tables, 3 Queries, and 2 Forms.

The issue I have run into so far, is that I am trying to drive a query using check boxes (not radio buttons). Each checkbox should, when selected, filter out any item that does not have a null or empty value from that field. I have included a screenshot of the form showing the 5 check boxes below.

[image: screenshot]

Currently, the query is working correctly as long as I do not select multiple check boxes (so not correctly, really). In the image, you can see that it is showing records with empty fields when the corresponding box is checked (which is not what I am wanting). It should, ideally, with everything checked, only show the Jamey Smith record in the screenshot.

Then, for example, With CCS and MICCS selected, it would only show the Ben Ward record.

Here's the SQL code:

```
SELECT 
    EmployeeInfo.[Last Name], 
    EmployeeInfo.[First Name], 
    EmployeeInfo.TWICS, 
    EmployeeInfo.CCS, 
    EmployeeInfo.MICCS, 
    EmployeeInfo.OSHA10, 
    EmployeeInfo.OSHA30
FROM 
    EmployeeInfo
WHERE (((EmployeeInfo.TWICS) Is Not Null)) 
AND (([Forms]![TestForm2]![optTWICS])=True)
OR (((EmployeeInfo.CCS) Is Not Null)
AND (([Forms]![TestForm2]![optCCS])=True)
OR ((EmployeeInfo.MICCS) Is Not Null)
AND (([Forms]![TestForm2]![optMICCS])=True)
OR ((EmployeeInfo.OSHA10) Is Not Null)
AND (([Forms]![TestForm2]![optOSHA10])=True)
OR ((EmployeeInfo.OSHA30) Is Not Null)
AND (([Forms]![TestForm2]![optOSHA30])=True));
```

I am sure my boolean logic is screwed. I have tried several approaches, changing the ORs to ANDs, as well as embedding the ANDs in IIF statements (and then changing ORs to ANDS). The embedded IIF statements work in that they will only show a record if every box is checked and the record has all of the fields as not null.

I would really appreciate a pointer here. I have been slogging through this all evening and I know I will spend my weekend with it just sitting somewhere in my brain. I tried this in VBA as well, but it was much more cumbersome and had the same issues.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure about the Access syntax for the checkbox values, but I did see some logical errors in your query that I fixed. This may be what you were trying to do.

```
SELECT 
    EmployeeInfo.[Last Name]
    , EmployeeInfo.[First Name]
    , EmployeeInfo.TWICS
    , EmployeeInfo.CCS
    , EmployeeInfo.MICCS
    , EmployeeInfo.OSHA10
    , EmployeeInfo.OSHA30
FROM EmployeeInfo
WHERE (EmployeeInfo.TWICS IS NOT NULL AND Forms![TestForm2]![optTWICS] = True)
    OR (EmployeeInfo.CCS IS NOT NULL AND Forms![TestForm2]![optCCS] = True)
    OR (EmployeeInfo.MICCS IS NOT NULL AND Forms![TestForm2]![optMICCS] = True)
    OR (EmployeeInfo.OSHA10 IS NOT NULL AND Forms![TestForm2]![optOSHA10] = True)
    OR (EmployeeInfo.OSHA30 IS NOT NULL AND Forms![TestForm2]![optOSHA30] = True);
```

Comment: Thanks for the clean-up, but I'm still not getting the query to run properly.  The Access code is running fine, I'm thinking the embedded logic in the SQL query isn't correct.  The only way I've been able to replicate what I want is to do a "Does Not Equal Blank" on the query screen.  Applying this to multiple columns does exactly what I want, in that I want to only show the records that do not have a null field for each date field.